# Mongodb busca que retorne arrays internos

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Exemplo de estrutura:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("598d4eb912f28534d80a5820"),
  "nome" : "Emilio",
  "produtos" : [
   {
     "_id" : ObjectId("598d4fb912f28534d80a5821"),
     "nome" : "produto1"
   },
   {
     "_id" : ObjectId("598d4fb912f28534d80a5822"),
     "nome" : "produto2"
   }
  ]
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("598d4eb912f28534d80a5821"),
  "nome" : "Zezinho",
  "produtos" : [
   {
     "_id" : ObjectId("598d4fb912f28534d80a5825"),
     "nome" : "produto3"
   }
  ]
}
```

Como faço para buscar somente os "produtos" de todos os usuarios e retornar algo assim:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("598d4fb912f28534d80a5821"),
  "nome" : "produto1"
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("598d4fb912f28534d80a5822"),
  "nome" : "produto2"
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("598d4fb912f28534d80a5825"),
  "nome" : "produto3"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer isso você precisa usar uma agregação (usei `teste` como o nome da collection):

```
db.teste.aggregate(
    {$unwind: "$produtos"},   
    {$project: {"_id" : "$produtos._id", "nome": "$produtos.nome"}}
)
```

O operador [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) desconstrói um campo array, retornando um documento independente para cada elemento.

Com o [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) você consegue dizer que campos serão mostrados na saída.

Se você vai listar todos os produtos com frequência, sugiro repensar o teu schema, seria melhor guardar os produtos em uma collection separada. Considera sempre como você vai acessar/modificar os dados para definir a estrutura.

Comment: só com o {$unwind: "$produtos"}, já me retorna separado mesmo estando no mesmo usuario, bacana, mas em $project teria que especificar um por um, o problema é que ao adicionar outro campo não seria automático...

Comment: Como eu comentei na resposta, se você vai listar somente produtos com frequência, dá uma pensada no teu schema, quem sabe colocando os produtos em uma collection separada.